# Is there an extention or a way to show order of called procedures in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I have a model which I have added many procedures incrementally over last year. I am thinking to check the logical flow of the simulation in an easier way other than following functions one by one. Another reason is to see why profiler listed some of procedures more than once with different execution time and number of calls. Is this a bug or it could happen ?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do something like this is to have informative print statements in each of the procedures. Something like `print "Procedure XX"` and you will have a list of procedures in the order they are called. Not very elegant, but it works :)

Comment: Thanks, I have used similar method when my program was smaller, I was looking for an easier way.

Comment: Anyway, if thats the only option I have , I will use it for all of my functions.

Comment: For this sort of change, one option is to use a good programmer's text editor, like Emacs or Vim or one of many others.  The NetLogo program is really just a text file.  It contains the source code that's in the Code tab, and followed by text from the Info tab, followed by text that specifies what's in the Interface tab.  After making a backup, with a good editor you can do a search and replace that finds every line that starts with `to` or `to-report`, then copies the name of the procedure, then adds a new line below that containing something like 'print (word "now in " <procedure-name>)'.

Comment: @Mars I don't know why I didn't see your comment earlier, its a good idea :)